# How to set the dynamic or static tick size in a Rickshaw.js plot?

Tags: javascript, plot, rickshaw

I am creating a Rickshaw.js-powered graph much like in this example: http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/tutorial/example_07.html based on my own data that is returned via an AJAX call. The data is either measured in bytes (typical values range in a few gigabytes or hundreds of MBs) or seconds (anywhere between 10s and 50 minutes). I tried using a `Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatBase1024KMGTP` formatter for the bytes and wrote my own for the seconds, which does its part well. The problem is that I need to position the tick lines in a smart way - preferably dynamically, but even static settings (e.g. place a tick every `1024*1024*1024=1 GB` or every `60 s`) would be fine.

I tried setting the `tickSize` to `1024^3` like so:

```
var y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y({
    graph: graph,
    tickSize: 1073741824 // 1 GB
});
y_axis.render();
```

but I ended up seeing no ticks at all. What am I doing wrong and what would be the right way?

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/issues/188
default tickSize in the example you gave is 4

Comment: @Mehdi Karamosly, so is my understanding correct that at this moment there exists a bug that would prevent me from using Rickshaw.js properly? If not, then could you elaborate? Perhaps provide a separate answer?

Comment: @HamishGrubijan Thanks for pointing me to Rickshaw.js. I used http://www.highcharts.com/ (which is excellent too) for the last 2 years, but it seems that library is getting some competition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, you need to adapt the `tickOffsets()` function of the [`Axis.X`](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X.js), [`Axis.Y`](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y.js) and [`Axis.Time`](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time.js) classes in Rickshaw.

`tickSize` will not help you with that as - like [@Old Pro stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16268806/1553481) correctly - it indicates the size of the bold tick lines in pixels. It has nothing to do with spacing.

### For Time-based Axes

My solution essentially consists of replacing the standard `tickOffsets()` function **in those files**

```
this.tickOffsets = function() {
    var domain = this.graph.x.domain();

    var unit = this.fixedTimeUnit || this.appropriateTimeUnit();
    var count = Math.ceil((domain[1] - domain[0]) / unit.seconds);

    var runningTick = domain[0];
    var offsets = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var tickValue = time.ceil(runningTick, unit);
        runningTick = tickValue + unit.seconds / 2;

        offsets.push( { value: tickValue, unit: unit } );
    }

    return offsets;
};
```

by a custom routine. This is gonna do the trick:

```
this.tickOffsets = function() {
    var domain = this.graph.x.domain();
    var unit = this.fixedTimeUnit || this.appropriateTimeUnit();

    var tickSpacing = args.tickSpacing || unit.seconds;
    var count = Math.ceil((domain[1] - domain[0]) / tickSpacing);

    var runningTick = domain[0];
    var offsets = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var tickValue = time.ceil(runningTick, unit);
        runningTick = tickValue + tickSpacing;

        offsets.push( { value: tickValue, unit: unit } );
    }
    return offsets;
};
```

With that in place, you can write something like

```
var time = new Rickshaw.Fixtures.Time();
var timeUnit = time.unit('year');

var x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.ExtendedTime( 
    { 
        graph: graph, 
        tickSpacing: 60*60*24*365*13, // 13 years
        timeUnit: timeUnit
    } );
```

to have ticks spaced out evenly at every 13 years.

### For Value-based Axes

For value-based Axes, you would need to extend the `render()` function to include a facility that "manually" sets the ticks for the axis. I did it like this:

```
this.render = function() {

    if (this.graph.height !== this._renderHeight) this.setSize({ auto: true });

    var axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.graph.y).orient(this.orientation);

    if (this.tickSpacing) {
        var tickValues = [];

        var min = Math.ceil(axis.scale().domain()[0]/this.tickSpacing);
        var max = Math.floor(axis.scale().domain()[1]/this.tickSpacing);

        for (i = min * this.tickSpacing; i < max; i += 1) {
            console.log(i);
            tickValues.push(i * this.tickSpacing);
        }
        axis.tickValues(tickValues);
    }

    axis.tickFormat( args.tickFormat || function(y) { return y } );

    if (this.orientation == 'left') {
        var berth = this.height * berthRate;
        var transform = 'translate(' + this.width + ', ' + berth + ')';
    }

    if (this.element) {
        this.vis.selectAll('*').remove();
    }

    this.vis
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", ["y_ticks", this.ticksTreatment].join(" "))
        .attr("transform", transform)
        .call(axis.ticks(this.ticks).tickSubdivide(0).tickSize(this.tickSize));

    var gridSize = (this.orientation == 'right' ? 1 : -1) * this.graph.width;

    this.graph.vis
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "y_grid")
        .call(axis.ticks(this.ticks).tickSubdivide(0).tickSize(gridSize));

    this._renderHeight = this.graph.height;
};
```

The important part here are the statements in the `if (this.tickSpacing)` clause. They compute ticks given by the `tickSpacing` variable in the config array, and assign them to the axis in the `axis.tickValues(tickValues)` statement. Note that `this.tickValues` is assigned in the `this.tickSpacing = args.tickSpacing` statement in the `initialize()` function, not stated above.

### Try it yourself

Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUkSm/4/), where the complete code is available. This will certainly give you some pointers. If you want, you can create your own jsfiddle with your values and tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: Doesn't work with timezones :( Always shows the GMT time, no matter what the settings are

Answer (score 1):

`tickSize` is the size of the ticks in pixels.  Not what you want to be setting to a huge number.

Set `ticks` to the number of ticks you want on the graph and Rickshaw (actually d3) will do some magic to give you pretty values of ticks that generate about that number of ticks on the graph.

If you want further control you're going to have to dig into [d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Home), where you will be able to explicitly set the tick values using [axis.tickValues()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues).  I'd probably copy the existing [Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y.js) code and create my own Y axis class that includes access to `tickValues` or the ability to use my own [scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_ticks).  It's a little unclean in that Rickshaw creates the Y scale in the `graph.render()` function, so you can't easily override the Y scale, but the Y scale Rickshaw creates does have the range set from the graph data, which is information you will want when creating your own tick values.

Comment: thank you. axis.tickValues should help, but A) How exactly should I call this function? B) How can I use custom logic for determining what the tick values should be? Small code examples are welcome. I am being picky because I put up bounty. I want to reward you for your hard work, but I feel that for my sake and for the sake of others the answer could be expanded. Thanks.

Comment: Rickshaw does not give you access to `tickValues()`.  It does not even let you replace the axis scale function because it generates it inside of `graph.render()`.  You'll have to rewrite and replace some of the Rickshaw code to get the full control that you want. It's not a simple thing.