# Rickshaw only show gridlines on some points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

I have a graph made with rickshaw:

[image: My graph]

I have the tick marks setup so that they only have a label if the value is -24, 0, or 24:

```
// Instantiate x-axis
var xAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
  graph: graph,
  orientation: 'bottom',
  pixelsPerTick: 25,
  element: graphXAxis,
  tickFormat: function(n) {
    switch(n) {
      case -24: return '24 hours ago';
      case 0: return 'Now';
      case 23: return '24 hours from now';
    }
  }
});
```

**But the gridlines show up on every single tick, even the ones that my case statement doesn't return for!
How can I get rid of the rest of the gridlines?**

Answer (score 5):

You can specify a desired number of ticks with the *ticks* key.  However that will not give you specific control over where those ticks are generated and you may not get exactly the number requested.  With some additional extension to RickShaw you can gain more control over the ticks, which is detailed with supporting code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223869/how-to-set-the-dynamic-or-static-tick-size-in-a-rickshaw-js-plot).

```
var xAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
  graph: graph,
  orientation: 'bottom',
  pixelsPerTick: 25,
  ticks:3,
  element: graphXAxis,
  tickFormat: function(n) {
    switch(n) {
      case -24: return '24 hours ago';
      case 0: return 'Now';
      case 23: return '24 hours from now';
    }
  }
});
```